# How to remove Vendor: from Dokan customer order emails

Tags: woocommerce, dokan

I am trying to remove the Vendor / Seller store name / URL from the emails that are sent to a customer when an order is placed.

I have looked everywhere and can find all of the email php files but still can't figure out how to remove the vendor. I can probably recreate the whole template but just want to make this simple change.

Answer (score 2):

When a customer purchases any product from the vendor that time a customer receives the default e-mail which sent by WooCommerce which is the new order email template. That should not have any vendor store details. Dokan is just adding the vendor email address with the admin e-mail to send the new-order notification to the vendor. Kindly check this function- `dokan_wc_email_recipient_add_seller`available in `dokan-lite/includes/functions.php`

If you can share a screenshot then I can provide the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook to remove the Vendor info

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'dokan_attach_vendor_name', 10, 2 );
```